# JasperReports in .Net over IKVM

Tags: .net, reporting, jasper-reports, ikvm

I'm willing to use JasperReports in .Net.

I used IKVM.net to build DLLs needed for this, and translated a sample app.

But I get a NotImplementedExeption in C# (the equivalent code in Java works perfectly)

```
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperFileDialog.FileName, null, new JREmptyDataSource());
```

> The method or operation is not implemented.

See stack trace below

---

**Notes:**
IKVM version: 0.40.0.1 http://sourceforge.net/projects/ikvm/files/ikvm/0.40.0.1/ikvmbin-0.40.0.1.zip/download

- Downloaded [JasperReports 3.7.0 project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/1.jasperreports/JasperReports%203.7.0/jasperreports-3.7.0-project.zip/download), grouped all jars in \lib and the [JasperReports-3.7.0.jar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/1.jasperreports/JasperReports%203.7.0/jasperreports-3.7.0.jar/download) in one folder
- Used **jar2ikvmc** to generate the ikmvc script http://code.google.com/p/jar2ikvmc/downloads/list
- Running the script I get alot of **ClassNotDefound** warnings
- Referenced all DLLs in the C# app, in addition to **all IKVM dlls** except ikvm-native.dll

---

Exception Stack Trace

```
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(Map parameterValues)
   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(Map parameterValues, JRDataSource ds)
   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JasperReport jasperReport, Map parameters, JRDataSource dataSource)
   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperReport jasperReport, Map parameters, JRDataSource dataSource)
   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(String sourceFileName, Map parameters, JRDataSource dataSource)
   at Jasper.Net.Form1.ExportButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Jasper.Net\Jasper.Net\Form1.cs:line 39
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at Jasper.Net.Program.Main() in C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Jasper.Net\Jasper.Net\Program.cs:line 18
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Try checking the method definition/declaration in generated dll using reflector

Comment: Your stacktrace does not show where the NotImplementedExeption come from. Without this information it is impossible to answer.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: no, I moved to Microsoft Reporting Services

Answer (score 1):

Usually the class not found exception occurs when the Jasper Reports jar depends on another jar. For example if the `jasperreport.jar` uses another jar like `log4net.jar`, you first need to convert the dependent jar to dll. Then used the converted dll for linking during the conversion of the jasperreport. I had the same problem when converting Apache POI to dll.